# Generate graphical report of all request and response of nodejs server

Tags: node.js, express

i am using nodejs as my server with express. I am logging all my request and response on server. Is there any package available to read my logs and generate graphical report like how many requests we got and how many succeeded. What was the request received and responded. Is there a package which can track all these details for me?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to get some performance metrics about your application which is great. There are many different ways you can go with this, here are a few suggestions for you to weigh up.

**Non-real-time performance metrics**

If you don't care about seeing the services real-time metrics you might want to create something to process them into a CSV and use something like excel or google sheets to generate graphs from them. If you need something immedietely and don't need to respond to things "in the moment" when a dip happens then this is a good quick and dirty solution.

**Real-time performance metrics using SaaS software**

If you want the metrics but don't want to host the systems yourself you might want to checkout services such as DataDog. They provide dashboards and graphs as a service. You can use something like statsd to get metrics into DataDog, or use their own integrations. They have a lot of integrations with cloud providers like AWS, GCP, and Azure for machine metrics (CPU etc). They also have packages for inteacting with your application itself such such as their [ExpressJS package](https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/express/).

**Real-time performance metrics using self-hosted solutions**

I've often used a self-hosted approach as I find the pricing often scales a bit better. The setup is fairly simple.

- Use a statsd package for all system components (nginx, nodejs, postgres, etc) to publish metrics to the statsd daemon.
- The statsd daemon self-hosted somewhere (maybe a proxy cluster if you're working on large applications).
- Self-hosted Graphite to consume metrics from the statsd daemon. Graphite is a software package designed for aggregating metrics and has an API for producing static graph images.
- Self-hosted Grafana that pulls metrics from graphite. Grafana is a real-time dashboarding software. It allows you to create multiple dashboards that hook into various data sources such as Graphite or other time series data stores.

The self-hosting route can take a day to setup but it does mean you don't increase your costs per-host. It's also easy to put behind internal networks if that's a requirement for your organisation.

Personally, I would recommend either real-time performance metrics approaches. If your application is small and doesn't have many hosts then services like DataDog could be useful and cost effective but if you do need to scale up you'll find your costs sky rocketing. At that point you might decide to move over to a self-hosted infrastructure.

Comment: I have hosted my app on kubernetes cluster. Anything i can use from there to do the metrics?

Comment: The approaches would be the same but you could also monitor your cluster with all three approaches. If you want application metrics you will have to emit them from the application somehow and capture them somewhere else. If you choose the self hosted route you can host statsd, graphite, and grafana all with docker as any other application, just make sure the graphite data store is some sort of mounted volume.